# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-express

I am getting the following error when I changed the path of the application -  from source control, source control took the latest version of the application but started giving me the following error.

This is the error messages that I am getting

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

[image]

Following is my Web config file

```
<configuration>
          <configSections>
            <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
          </configSections>
          <connectionStrings>

            <remove name="DefaultConnection" />

        <!-- sys_IMS_Test is the user executing SPs-->
            <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Initial Catalog=ED_InvestigationManagementSystem;Data Source=NETSQL-TEST.ad.arb.ca.gov;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
            <add name="OISLogConnection" connectionString="Initial Catalog=OISLOG;Data Source=netsql-test;uid=OISLOGUser;password=Nettest217;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
            <add name="BlobConnection" connectionString="Initial Catalog=ED_IMS_Blobs;Data Source=netsql-test;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


          </connectionStrings>
          <appSettings>
            <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
            <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
            <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
            <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
            <add key="LogSQL" value="false" />

            <!-- SSRS -->
            <add key="NetworkUserName" value="IMSReportsUser" />
            <add key="NetworkUserPassword" value="jklqwe123" />
            <add key="NetworkUserDomain" value="carb" />


            <add key="ReportServerUrl" value="http://netsql-test/ReportServer?/IMS/Reports/" />
            <!-- This setting will be adjusted with Build/Test Web.Config versions -->
            <add key="BuildType" value="dev" />
            <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="90000000000000000" />
            <add key="ApiClientKey" value="705a69e4-8edd-4f18-92bb-850dfc9711b2" />
            <add key="ApiServerUrl" value="http://localhost:5000" />

            <!--Application Logging-->
            <add key="LogType" value="40" />
            <!--10 = ALL; 20 = Info/Warnings/Errors 30 = Warnings/Errors; 40 = Errors only; 99 = disable logging-->

            <!--Email Logging-->
            <add key="SMTPServer" value="fdcmailer.ad.arb.ca.gov"/>
            <add key="SMTPPort" value="25"/>
            <add key="EmailFrom" value="DoNotReplyErrorInIMS@arb.ca.gov"/>
            <add key="EmailTo" value="Abdul.Aleem@arb.ca.gov" />
            <add key="EmailCC" value="Ken.Stark@arb.ca.gov;mike.ellis@arb.ca.gov" />
            <add key="EmailSubject" value="Servere Error Happened in the IMS Application" />
            <add key="ReplyTo" value="DoNotReplyErrorInIMS@arb.ca.gov" />
            <!--If the value of EnableCertificate is anything other than 0 then its true, to disable Certificates -->
            <add key="EnableCertificate" value="0" />        
          </appSettings>

          <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="Off" />
            <authentication mode="None" />
            <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
            <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="20971520" />
            <machineKey validationKey="EF77A2146AFDC7B914EB901BFED8DB84D441956690EDB4323C6D56A33504D6CCC66675143BEBD244CB44D42468BBBBE51F694B21692653A722FC9B9CAF0D1515" decryptionKey="7F0CBFB9B915073F237607176BE26CE25435BC5CBC45ECF3C6CAFDAC53C7B314" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />

          </system.web>
          <system.net>
            <mailSettings>
              <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
                <network host="146.114.248.200" port="25" defaultCredentials="true" />
              </smtp>
            </mailSettings>
          </system.net>
          <system.webServer>

            <handlers>
              <!--register windows login managed handler.-->
              <add name="Windows Login Handler" path="Login" verb="POST" type="IMS.Web.WindowsLoginHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" />
              <!--these handlers resolve .woff not showing problem-->
              <add name="fonts" path="*.woff" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
              <add name="fonts2" path="*.woff2" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />

              <!-- SSRS -->
              <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />


              <remove name="WebDAV" />

            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" /><remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /><remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" /><add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /></handlers>
            <modules>
              <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
            </modules>
            <security>
              <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
              </authentication>
              <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
              </requestFiltering>
            </security>
            <staticContent>
              <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
              <remove fileExtension=".less" />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="stylesheet/less" />
              <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
              <remove fileExtension=".hbs" />
              <mimeMap fileExtension=".hbs" mimeType="text/x-handlebars-template" />
            </staticContent>
          </system.webServer>
          <runtime>
            <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Xml" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Core" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
              <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
              </dependentAssembly>
            </assemblyBinding>
          </runtime>
          <entityFramework>
            <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
              <parameters>
                <parameter value="v11.0" />
              </parameters>
            </defaultConnectionFactory>
            <providers>
              <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
            </providers>
          </entityFramework>
        </configuration>
```

Comment: Post the configuration file.

Comment: Its resolved by modifying the applicationhost.config file under the solution folder from

Comment: <section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
<add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
<add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="true" />
to
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<section name="anonymousAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
<add name="AnonymousAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />
<add name="WindowsAuthenticationModule" lockItem="false" />

Comment: That might work for VS/IIS Express, but unlocking such sections only increases security risks of your web server in your final deployment to IIS.

Comment: Beautiful - can you you please let me know what is the other approach that we can resolve the issue? And that too, I didn't make this change on the Server, the applicationhost.config file is modified only on the local development machine, does it still effects the Server my friend? Thanks for giving your suggestion.